# Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, security, quoting

If you've been following unix.stackexchange.com for a while, you
should hopefully know by now that leaving a variable
unquoted in list context (as in `echo $var`) in Bourne/POSIX
shells (zsh being the exception) has a very special meaning and
shouldn't be done unless you have a very good reason to.

It's discussed at length in a number of Q&A here (Examples: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766), [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694), [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963), [Quoted vs unquoted string expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78914))

That has been the case since the initial release of the Bourne
shell in the late 70s and hasn't been changed by the Korn shell
(one of [David Korn's biggest
regrets (question #7)](https://news.slashdot.org/story/01/02/06/2030205/david-korn-tells-all)) or `bash` which mostly
copied the Korn shell, and that's how that has been specified by POSIX/Unix.

Now, we're still seeing a number of answers here and even
occasionally publicly released shell code where
variables are not quoted. You'd have thought people would have
learnt by now.

In my experience, there are mainly 3 types of people who omit to
quote their variables:

- beginners. Those can be excused as admittedly it's a
  completely unintuitive syntax. And it's our role on this site
  to educate them.
- forgetful people.
- people who are not convinced even after repeated hammering,
  who think that *surely the Bourne shell author did not
  intend us to quote all our variables*.

Maybe we can convince them if we expose the risk associated with
this kind of behaviours.

What's the worst thing that can possibly happen if you
forget to quote your variables. Is it really *that* bad?

What kind of vulnerability are we talking of here?

In what contexts can it be a problem?

Comment: [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) is something you'll like I think.

Comment: backlink from [this article I wrote](https://www.mirbsd.org/permalinks/wlog-10_e20141209-tg.htm), thanks for the writeup

Comment: One reason for not using double quotes around variables in shell scripts is that in most editors syntax highlighting no longer emphasizes variable names then ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl you should report that as a bug to the maintainers of the editor you use. That would be very bad if their syntax highlighting encouraged bad coding practice. `vim` doesn't have that problem AFAICT. Neither does `jed`. Having said, shell code (especially Bourne-like ones)  syntax highlight is virtually impossible to do reliably (or usefully).

Comment: There's a fourth case where people fail to quote properly: when you have a construct like `"$( cmd "$var" )"`, many sophomores leave out one of the pairs of quotes, and are surprised when you tell them they haven't put in *enough* quotes. Some of them even argue that extra quotes would make it break up into `"$( cmd "` `$var` `" )"`

Answer (score 290, accepted):

### Preamble

First, I'd say it's not the right way to address the problem.
It's a bit like saying "*you should not murder people because
otherwise you'll go to jail*".

Similarly, you don't quote your variable because otherwise
you're introducing security vulnerabilities. You quote your
variables because it is wrong not to (but if the fear of the jail can help, why not).

A little summary for those who've just jumped on the train.

In most shells, leaving a variable expansion unquoted (though
that (and the rest of this answer) also applies to command
substitution (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`) and arithmetic expansion (`$((...))` or `$[...]`)) has a very special
meaning. The best way to describe it is that it is like
invoking some sort of implicit *split+glob* operator¹.

```
cmd $var
```

in another language would be written something like:

```
cmd(glob(split($var)))
```

`$var` is first split into a list of words according to complex
rules involving the `$IFS` special parameter (the *split* part)
and then each word resulting of that splitting is considered as
a *pattern* which is expanded to a list of files that match it
(the *glob* part).

As an example, if `$var` contains `*.txt,/var/*.xml` and `$IFS`
contains `,`, `cmd` would be called with a number of arguments,
the first one being `cmd` and the next ones being the `txt`
files in the current directory and the `xml` files in `/var`.

If you wanted to call `cmd` with just the two literal arguments `cmd`
and `*.txt,/var/*.xml`, you'd write:

```
cmd "$var"
```

which would be in your other more familiar language:

```
cmd($var)
```

### What do we mean by *vulnerability in a shell*?

After all, it's been known since the dawn of time that shell
scripts should not be used in security-sensitive contexts.
Surely,  OK, leaving a variable unquoted is a bug but that can't
do that much harm, can it?

Well, despite the fact that anybody would tell you that shell
scripts should never be used for web CGIs, or that thankfully
most systems don't allow setuid/setgid shell scripts nowadays,
one thing that shellshock (the remotely exploitable bash bug
that made the headlines in September 2014) revealed is that
shells are still extensively used where they probably shouldn't:
in CGIs, in DHCP client hook scripts, in sudoers commands,
invoked *by* (if not *as*) setuid commands...

Sometimes unknowingly. For instance `system('cmd $PATH_INFO')`
in a `php`/`perl`/`python` CGI script does invoke a shell to interpret that command line (not to
mention the fact that `cmd` itself may be a shell script and its
author may have never expected it to be called from a CGI).

You've got a vulnerability when there's a path for privilege
escalation, that is when someone (let's call him *the attacker*)
is able to do something he is not meant to.

Invariably that means *the attacker* providing data, that data
being processed by a privileged user/process which inadvertently
does something it shouldn't be doing, in most of the cases because
of a bug.

Basically, you've got a problem when your buggy code processes
data under the control of *the attacker*.

Now, it's not always obvious where that *data* may come from,
and it's often hard to tell if your code will ever get to
process untrusted data.

As far as variables are concerned, In the case of a CGI script,
it's quite obvious, the data are the CGI GET/POST parameters and
things like cookies, path, host... parameters.

For a setuid script (running as one user when invoked by
another), it's the arguments or environment variables.

Another very common vector is file names. If you're getting a
file list from a directory, it's possible that files have been
planted there by *the attacker*.

In that regard, even at the prompt of an interactive shell, you
could be vulnerable (when processing files in `/tmp` or `~/tmp`
for instance).

Even a `~/.bashrc` can be vulnerable (for instance, `bash` will
interpret it when invoked over `ssh` to run a `ForcedCommand`
like in `git` server deployments with some variables under the
control of the client).

Now, a script may not be called directly to process untrusted
data, but it may be called by another command that does. Or your
incorrect code may be copy-pasted into scripts that do (by you 3
years down the line or one of your colleagues). One place where it's
particularly *critical* is in answers in Q&A sites as you'll
never know where copies of your code may end up.

### Down to business; how bad is it?

Leaving a variable (or command substitution) unquoted is by far
the number one source of security vulnerabilities associated
with shell code. Partly because those bugs often translate to
vulnerabilities but also because it's so common to see unquoted
variables.

Actually, when looking for vulnerabilities in shell code, the
first thing to do is look for unquoted variables. It's easy to
spot, often a good candidate, generally easy to track back to
attacker-controlled data.

There's an infinite number of ways an unquoted variable can turn
into a vulnerability. I'll just give a few common trends here.

#### Information disclosure

Most people will bump into bugs associated with unquoted
variables because of the *split* part (for instance, it's
common for files to have spaces in their names nowadays and space
is in the default value of IFS). Many people will overlook the
*glob* part. The *glob* part is at least as dangerous as the
*split* part.

Globbing done upon unsanitised external input means *the
attacker* can make you read the content of any directory.

In:

```
echo You entered: $unsanitised_external_input
```

if `$unsanitised_external_input` contains `/*`, that means *the
attacker* can see the content of `/`. No big deal. It becomes
more interesting though with `/home/*` which gives you a list of
user names on the machine, `/tmp/*`,  `/home/*/.forward` for
hints at other dangerous practises, `/etc/rc*/*` for enabled
services... No need to name them individually. A value of `/* /*/* /*/*/*...` will just list the whole file system.

#### Denial of service vulnerabilities.

Taking the previous case a bit too far and we've got a DoS.

Actually, any unquoted variable in list context with unsanitized
input is *at least* a DoS vulnerability.

Even expert shell scripters commonly forget to quote things
like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
: ${QUERYSTRING=$1}
```

`:` is the no-op command. What could possibly go wrong?

That's meant to assign `$1` to `$QUERYSTRING` if `$QUERYSTRING`
was unset. That's a quick way to make a CGI script callable from
the command line as well.

That `$QUERYSTRING` is still expanded though and because it's
not quoted, the *split+glob* operator is invoked.

Now, there are some globs that are particularly expensive to
expand. The `/*/*/*/*` one is bad enough as it means listing
directories up to 4 levels down. In addition to the disk and CPU
activity, that means storing tens of thousands of file paths
(40k here on a minimal server VM, 10k of which directories).

Now `/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*` means 40k x 10k and
`/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*` is enough to
bring even the mightiest machine to its knees.

Try it for yourself (though be prepared for your machine to
crash or hang):

```
a='/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*' sh -c ': ${a=foo}'
```

Of course, if the code is:

```
echo $QUERYSTRING > /some/file
```

Then you can fill up the disk.

Just do a google search on [shell
cgi](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=shell+cgi) or [bash
cgi](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bash+cgi) or [ksh
cgi](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ksh+cgi), and you'll find
a few pages that show you how to write CGIs in shells. Notice
how half of those that process parameters are vulnerable.

Even [David Korn's
own
one](https://web.archive.org/web/20150430175848/http://www2.research.att.com/%7Eastopen/download/ksh/scripts/cgi-lib.ksh)
is vulnerable (look at the cookie handling).

#### up to arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities

Arbitrary code execution is the worst type of vulnerability,
since if *the attacker* can run any command, there's no limit on
what he may do.

That's generally the *split* part that leads to those. That
splitting results in several arguments to be passed to commands
when only one is expected. While the first of those will be used
in the expected context, the others will be in a different context
so potentially interpreted differently. Better with an example:

```
awk -v foo=$external_input '$2 == foo'
```

Here, the intention was to assign the content of the
`$external_input` shell variable to the `foo` `awk` variable.

Now:

```
$ external_input='x BEGIN{system("uname")}'
$ awk -v foo=$external_input '$2 == foo'
Linux
```

The second word resulting of the splitting of `$external_input`
is not assigned to `foo` but considered as `awk` code (here that
executes an arbitrary command: `uname`).

That's especially a problem for commands that can execute other
commands (`awk`, `env`, `sed` (GNU one), `perl`, `find`...) especially
with the GNU variants (which accept options after arguments).
Sometimes, you wouldn't suspect commands to be able to execute
others like `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh`'s `[` or `printf`...

```
for file in *; do
  [ -f $file ] || continue
  something-that-would-be-dangerous-if-$file-were-a-directory
done
```

If we create a directory called `x -o yes`, then the test
becomes positive, because it's a completely different
conditional expression we're evaluating.

Worse, if we create a file called `x -a a[0$(uname>&2)] -gt 1`,
with all ksh implementations at least (which includes the `sh`
of most commercial Unices and some BSDs), that executes `uname`
because those shells perform arithmetic evaluation on the
numerical comparison operators of the `[` command.

```
$ touch x 'x -a a[0$(uname>&2)] -gt 1'
$ ksh -c 'for f in *; do [ -f $f ]; done'
Linux
```

Same with `bash` for a filename like `x -a -v a[0$(uname>&2)]`.

Of course, if they can't get arbitrary execution, *the attacker* may
settle for lesser damage (which may help to get arbitrary
execution). Any command that can write files or change
permissions, ownership or have any main or side effect could be exploited.

All sorts of things can be done with file names.

```
$ touch -- '-R ..'
$ for file in *; do [ -f "$file" ] && chmod +w $file; done
```

And you end up making `..` writeable (recursively with GNU
`chmod`).

Scripts doing automatic processing of files in publicly writable areas like `/tmp` are to be written very carefully.

#### What about `[ $# -gt 1 ]`

That's something I find exasperating. Some people go down all
the trouble of wondering whether a particular expansion may be
problematic to decide if they can omit the quotes.

It's like saying. *Hey, it looks like `$#` cannot be subject to
the split+glob operator, let's ask the shell to split+glob it*.
Or *Hey, let's write incorrect code just because the bug is
unlikely to be hit*.

Now how unlikely is it? OK, `$#` (or `$!`, `$?` or any
arithmetic substitution) may only contain digits (or `-` for
some²) so the *glob* part is out. For the *split* part to do
something though, all we need is for `$IFS` to contain digits (or `-`).

With some shells, `$IFS` may be inherited from the environment,
but if the environment is not safe, it's game over anyway.

Now if you write a function like:

```
my_function() {
  [ $# -eq 2 ] || return
  ...
}
```

What that means is that the behaviour of your function depends
on the context in which it is called. Or in other words, `$IFS`
becomes one of the inputs to it. Strictly speaking, when you
write the API documentation for your function, it should be
something like:

```
# my_function
#   inputs:
#     $1: source directory
#     $2: destination directory
#   $IFS: used to split $#, expected not to contain digits...
```

And code calling your function needs to make sure `$IFS` doesn't
contain digits. All that because you didn't feel like typing
those 2 double-quote characters.

Now, for that `[ $# -eq 2 ]` bug to become a vulnerability,
you'd need somehow for the value of `$IFS` to become under
control of *the attacker*. Conceivably, that would not normally
happen unless *the attacker* managed to exploit another bug.

That's not unheard of though. A common case is when people
forget to sanitize data before using it in arithmetic
expression. We've already seen above that it can allow
arbitrary code execution in some shells, but in all of them, it allows
*the attacker* to give any variable an integer value.

For instance:

```
n=$(($1 + 1))
if [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Too many arguments"
  exit 1
fi
```

And with a `$1` with value `(IFS=-1234567890)`, that arithmetic
evaluation has the side effect of settings IFS and the next `[`
command fails which means the check for *too many args* is
bypassed.

#### What about when the *split+glob* operator is not invoked?

There's another case where quotes are needed around variables and other expansions: when it's used as a pattern.

```
[[ $a = $b ]]   # a `ksh` construct also supported by `bash`
case $a in ($b) ...; esac
```

do not test whether `$a` and `$b` are the same (except with `zsh`) but if `$a` matches the pattern in `$b`. And you need to quote `$b` if you want to compare as strings (same thing in `"${a#$b}"` or `"${a%$b}"` or `"${a##*$b*}"` where `$b` should be quoted if it's not to be taken as a pattern).

What that means is that `[[ $a = $b ]]` may return true in cases where `$a` is different from `$b` (for instance when `$a` is `anything` and `$b` is `*`) or may return false when they are identical (for instance when both `$a` and `$b` are `[a]`).

Can that make for a security vulnerability? Yes, like any bug. Here, *the attacker* can alter your script's logical code flow and/or break the assumptions that your script are making. For instance, with a code like:

```
if [[ $1 = $2 ]]; then
   echo >&2 '$1 and $2 cannot be the same or damage will incur'
   exit 1
fi
```

*The attacker* can bypass the check by passing `'[a]' '[a]'`.

Now, if neither that pattern matching nor the *split+glob* operator apply, what's the danger of leaving a variable unquoted?

I have to admit that I do write:

```
a=$b
case $a in...
```

There, quoting doesn't harm but is not strictly necessary.

However, one side effect of omitting quotes in those cases (for instance in Q&A answers) is that it can send a wrong message to beginners: <strike>*that it may be all right not to quote variables*</strike>.

For instance, they may start thinking that if `a=$b` is OK, then <strike>`export a=$b`</strike> would be as well (which [it's not in many shells](/a/97569/135943) as it's in arguments to the `export` command so in list context) or <strike>`env a=$b`</strike>.

There are a few places though where quotes are not accepted. The main one being inside Korn-style arithmetic expressions in many shells like in `echo "$(( $1 + 1 ))" "${array[$1 + 1]}" "${var:$1 + 1}"` where the `$1` must not be quoted (being in a list context --the arguments to a simple command-- the overall expansions still needs to be quoted though).

Inside those, the shell understands a separate language altogether inspired from C. In AT&T `ksh` for instance `$(( 'd' - 'a' ))` expands to 3 like it does in C and not the same as `$(( d - a ))` would. Double quotes are ignored in ksh93 but cause a syntax error in many other shells. In C, `"d" - "a"` would return the difference between pointers to C strings. Doing the same in shell would not make sense.

#### What about `zsh`?

`zsh` did fix most of those design awkwardnesses. In `zsh` (at least when not in sh/ksh emulation mode), if you want *splitting*, or *globbing*, or *pattern matching*, you have to request it explicitly: `$=var` to split, and `$~var` to glob or for the content of the variable to be treated as a pattern.

However, splitting (but not globbing) is still done implicitly upon unquoted command substitution (as in `echo $(cmd)`).

Also, a sometimes unwanted side effect of not quoting variable is the *empties removal*. The `zsh` behaviour is similar to what you can achieve in other shells by disabling globbing altogether (with `set -f`) and splitting (with `IFS=''`). Still, in:

```
cmd $var
```

There will be no *split+glob*, but if `$var` is empty, instead of receiving one empty argument, `cmd` will receive no argument at all.

That can cause bugs (like the obvious `[ -n $var ]`). That can possibly break a script's expectations and assumptions and cause vulnerabilities.

As the empty variable can cause an argument to be just *removed*, that means the  next argument could be interpreted in the wrong context.

As an example,

```
printf '[%d] <%s>\n' 1 $attacker_supplied1 2 $attacker_supplied2
```

If `$attacker_supplied1` is empty,  then `$attacker_supplied2` will be interpreted as an arithmetic expression (for `%d`) instead of a string (for `%s`) and [any unsanitized data used in an arithmetic expression is a command injection vulnerability in Korn-like shells such as zsh](/q/172103).

```
$ attacker_supplied1='x y' attacker_supplied2='*'
$ printf '[%d] <%s>\n' 1 $attacker_supplied1 2 $attacker_supplied2
[1] <x y>
[2] <*>
```

fine, but:

```
$ attacker_supplied1='' attacker_supplied2='psvar[$(uname>&2)0]'
$ printf '[%d] <%s>\n' 1 $attacker_supplied1 2 $attacker_supplied2
Linux
[1] <2>
[0] <>
```

The `uname` *arbitrary command* was run.

Also note that while `zsh` doesn't do globbing upon substitutions by default, as globs in zsh are much more powerful than in other shells, that means they can do a lot more damage if ever you enabled the `globsubst` option at the same time of the `extendedglob` one, or without disabling `bareglobqual` and left some variables unintentionally unquoted.

For instance, even:

```
set -o globsubst
echo $attacker_controlled
```

Would be an arbitrary command execution vulnerability, because commands can be executed as part of glob expansions, for instance with the `e`valuation glob qualifier:

```
$ set -o globsubst
$ attacker_controlled='.(e[uname])'
$ echo $attacker_controlled
Linux
.
```

```
emulate sh # or ksh
echo $attacker_controlled
```

doesn't cause an ACE vulnerability (though it still a DoS one like in sh) because `bareglobqual` is disabled in sh/ksh emulation. There's no good reason to enable `globsubst` other than in those sh/ksh emulations when wanting to interpret sh/ksh code.

#### What about when you *do* need the *split+glob* operator?

Yes, that's typically when you do want to leave your variable unquoted. But then you need to make sure you tune your *split* and *glob* operators correctly before using it. If you only want the *split* part and not the *glob* part (which is the case most of the time), then you do need to disable globbing (`set -o noglob`/`set -f`) and fix `$IFS`. Otherwise you'll cause vulnerabilities as well (like David Korn's CGI example mentioned above).

### Conclusion

In short, leaving a variable (or command substitution or
arithmetic expansion) unquoted in shells can be very dangerous
indeed especially when done in the wrong contexts, and it's very
hard to know which are those wrong contexts.

That's one of the reasons why it is considered *bad practice*.

Thanks for reading so far. If it goes over your head, don't
worry. One can't expect everyone to understand all the implications of
writing their code the way they write it. That's why we have
*good practice recommendations*, so they can be followed without
necessarily understanding why.

(and in case that's not obvious yet, please avoid writing
security sensitive code in shells).

And **please quote your variables on your answers on this site!**

---

<sup>¹In `ksh93` and `pdksh` and derivatives, *brace expansion* is also performed unless globbing is disabled (in the case of `ksh93` versions up to ksh93u+, even when the `braceexpand` option is disabled).</sup>

<sup>² In `ksh93` and `yash`, arithmetic expansions can also include things like `1,2`, `1e+66`, `inf`, `nan`. There are even more in `zsh`, including `#` which is a glob operator with `extendedglob`, but `zsh` never does split+glob upon arithmetic expansion, even in `sh` emulation</sup>

Comment: Note that, with `[[`, only the RHS of comparisons needs to be quoted: `if [[ $1 = "$2" ]]; then`

Comment: @mirabilos, yes, but the LHS needs not **not** to be quoted, so there's no compelling reason not to quote it there (if we're to take the conscious decision to _quote by default_ as it seems to be the most sensible thing to do). Also note that `[[ $* = "$var" ]]` is not the same as `[[ "$*" = "$var" ]]` if the first character of `$IFS` is not space with `bash` (and also `mksh` if `$IFS` is empty though in that case I'm not sure what `$*` is equal to, should I raise a bug?)).

Comment: Yeah, you can quote by default there. Please no more bugs about field splitting right now, I’ve still got to fix those I know about (from you and others) first, before we can re-evaluate this.

Comment: Wow, that is an extremely thorough answer. It would probably be helpful to mention one vulnerability that **doesn't** exist, but is naively assumed by some people: `foo=bar; rm *` will not cause execution of `rm *` if you do `echo $foo`.

Comment: @Barmar, assuming you meant `foo='bar; rm *'`, no it won't, it will however list the content of the current directory which may count as an information disclosure. `print $foo` in `ksh93` (where `print` is the replacement for `echo` that addresses some of its shortcomings) does have a code injection vulnerability though (for instance with `foo='-f%.0d z[0$(uname>&2)]'`) (you actually need `print -r -- "$foo"`. `echo "$foo"` is still wrong and not fixable (though generally less harmfull)).

Comment: I wondered how to get the IFS+set=split thing you pointed out in Korn's cookie handling secure. Today in #ksh on IRC I asked whether set ±o noglob around it would be enough; nobody complained. Is it?

Comment: @mirabilos. Yes, see how he's already using `set -f` in other functions (note there's a local scope for options inside `function f {` declared functions in ksh93)

Comment: I'm no bash expert, but I've been coding in it for over a decade. I used quotes a lot, but mainly to handle embedded blanks. Now, I'll use them a lot more! It would be nice if someone would expand on this answer to make it a little easier to absorb all the fine points. I got a lot of it, but I missed a lot too. It's a long post already, but I know there's a lot more here for me to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you for this very thorough and well-written post. When you say about `zsh`: "or `$var` to be treated as a _pattern_", did you mean _literal_?
Allow me a shameless plug, but I do think it's pertinent: my [`shall`](https://github.com/mklement0/shall) utility makes cross-POSIX-like-shell testing easy.

Comment: @mklement0, see if the edit makes it clearer. It was intended as _$~var to glob, and $~var for $var to be treated as a pattern_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yes, that's clearer, thanks; I suggest two small tweaks: "$=var to split>>, and<< $~var to glob or >>for<< the content of the variable to be treated as a pattern.

Comment: Acording to [this site](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html), the first line after the figure: `Splits the command into tokens that are separated by the fixed set of metacharacters: SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE, ;, (, ), <, >, |, and &. Types of tokens include words, keywords, I/O redirectors, and semicolons.` That is, the first split is FIXED, not afected by IFS. To test do IFS=23; echo hello             world`, the spaces are removed even not being in the IFS value. Meta-characters are fixed.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, yes though it's not relevant to this Q&A where we talk about split+glob done on unquoted variables (and other expansions). Note that in the Bourne shell $IFS splitting also occurred on unquoted non-expanded words (in addition to tokenising) as in `IFS=i; edit foo` would run `ed` on `t` and `foo`. Also note that in bash, it's all blanks, not only space and tab (though it doesn't work properly for multibyte characters)

Comment: Ok, took me a while to get the point that you were talking of Bourne shell. The finner points are quite well [explained in this web page](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html#para:bash-ksh) search for `only if the argument is non-constant`, and the description below for Bourne shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you give a couple of examples of: `all blanks` and: `doesn't work properly for multibyte characters`? Thanks.

Comment: @BinaryZebra see http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/22367. In practice, except for malicious locales, the only blanks in single-byte-character locales other than space and tab I've ever come across was the non-breaking space in iso8859-* charsets on Solaris (not that I've done an extensive search).

Comment: You could also mention that because `cmd $var` is `cmd(glob(split($var)))` so it is **slower** then `cmd "$vaf"`. I'm not sure whether this is still true in `zsh`.

Comment: I was shocked to see the awk example, because I thought the entire point of `-v` was to avoid awk code injection from interpolating directly into the script. I couldn't get the example injection to work on GNU awk 4.2.1, though. If this example was also using GNU awk, it seems they fixed the bug then.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread what the example was doing, and couldn't see it because zsh apparently doesn't wordsplit when the variable is interpolated in another string. Works in bash as shown.

Comment: +1 for implying an unquoted variable is as bad as murder <3

Comment: Reading this wonderfull answer, I immediately took action, because I remembered having used unquoted `$#` and the likes in my latest script. Now it doesn't run no more. Try running this little code to split a value into an integer and a multiplier: `units=bkmgt value=235g unit="${value}" value="${value%[$units]}" unit="${unit:"${#value}"}"` , which fails on the last assignment because of the additional quotes I added around `${#value}`. The lesson is: good advice is only good when used with caution.

Comment: @db-inf, I take it that's mksh or some older version of zsh? See edit.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas : No, it is GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 47):

[Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286107/80216#286192) by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas).]

## But what if …?

> But what if my script sets a variable to a known value before using it? 
> In particular, what if it sets a variable to one of two or more
> possible values (but it *always* sets it to something known),
> and none of the values contain space or glob characters? 
> Isn’t it safe to use it without quotes *in that case*?
>
> And what if one of the possible values is the empty string,
> and I’m depending on “empties removal”? 
> I.e., if the variable contains the empty string,
> I don’t want to get the empty string in my command;
> I want to get nothing. 
> For example,

```
if some_condition
then
    ignorecase="-i"
else
    ignorecase=""
fi
                                  # Note that the quotes in the above commands are not strictly needed.
grep  $ignorecase  other_grep_args
```

I can’t say `grep "$ignorecase" other_grep_args`;
that will fail if `$ignorecase` is the empty string.

#### Response:

As discussed in the other answer,
this will still fail if `IFS` contains a `-` or an `i`. 
If you have ensured that `IFS` doesn’t contain any character in your variable
(and you are sure that your variable doesn’t contain any glob characters),
then this is probably safe.

But there is a way that is safer
(although it’s somewhat ugly and quite unintuitive):
use `${ignorecase:+"$ignorecase"}`. 
From [the POSIX Shell Command Language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html),
under [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02),

> `${parameter:+[word]}`
>
>   **Use Alternative Value.**
>   If
>   *`parameter`*
>   is unset or null, null shall be substituted;
>   otherwise, the expansion of
>   *`word`*
>   (or an empty string if
>   *`word`*
>   is omitted) shall be substituted.

The trick here, such as it is,
is that we are using `ignorecase` as the *`parameter`*
and `"$ignorecase"` as the *`word`*. 
So `${ignorecase:+"$ignorecase"}` means

> If `$ignorecase` is unset or null (i.e., empty),
> null (i.e., unquoted *nothing*) shall be substituted;
> otherwise, the expansion of `"$ignorecase"` shall be substituted.

This gets us where we want to go:
if the variable is set to the empty string,
it will be “removed” (this entire, convoluted expression
will evaluate to *nothing* — not even an empty string),
and if the variable has a non-empty value, we get that value, quoted.

​

---

## But what if …?

> But what if I have a variable that I want/need to be split into words? 
> (This is otherwise like the first case; my script has set the variable,
> and I’m sure it doesn’t contain any glob characters. 
> But it might contain space(s),
> and I want it split into separate arguments at the space boundaries.  
> P.S. I still want empties removal.)
>
> For example,

```
if some_condition
then
    criteria="-type f"
else
    criteria=""
fi
if some_other_condition
then
    criteria="$criteria -mtime +42"
fi
find "$start_directory"  $criteria  other_find_args
```

#### Response:

<del>You might think that this is a case for using `eval`.</del> 
**No!** 
Resist the temptation to even think about using `eval` here.

Again, if you have ensured that `IFS` doesn’t contain
any character in your variable
(except for the spaces, which you want to be honored),
and you are sure that your variable doesn’t contain any glob characters,
then the above is probably safe.

But, if you’re using bash (or ksh, zsh or yash),
there is a way that is safer: use an array:

```
if some_condition
then
    criteria=(-type f)  # You could say `criteria=("-type" "f")`, but it’s really unnecessary.
                        # But do not say `criteria=("-type f")` or `criteria="(-type f)"`.
else
    criteria=()         # Do not use any quotes on this command!
fi
if some_other_condition
then
    criteria+=(-mtime +42)      # Note: not `=`, but `+=`, to add (append) to an array.
fi
find "$start_directory"  "${criteria[@]}"  other_find_args
```

From [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html),

> Any element of an array may be referenced
> using `${name[subscript]}`. 
> …  If *`subscript`* is **`@`** or **`*`**,
> the word expands to all members of *`name`*. 
> These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. 
> If the word is double-quoted, … `${name[@]}`
> expands each element of *`name`* to a separate word.

So `"${criteria[@]}"` expands to (in the above example)
the zero, two, or four elements of the `criteria` array, each quoted. 
In particular, if neither of the *condition* s is true,
the `criteria` array has no contents
(as set by the `criteria=()` statement),
and `"${criteria[@]}"` evaluates to *nothing*
(not even an inconvenient empty string).

---

This gets especially interesting and complicated
when you are dealing with multiple words,
some of which are dynamic (user) input, which you don’t know in advance,
and may contain space(s) or other special character(s). 
Consider:

```
printf "Enter file name to look for: "
read fname
if [ "$fname" != "" ]
then
    criteria+=(-name "$fname")
fi
```

Note that `$fname` is quoted *each* time it is used. 
This works even if the user enters something like `foo bar` or `foo*`; 
`"${criteria[@]}"` evaluates to `-name "foo bar"` or `-name "foo*"`. 
(Remember that each element of the array is quoted.)

Arrays don’t work in all POSIX shells;
arrays are a ksh / bash / zsh / yash-ism. 
Except … there’s *one* array that all shells support:
the argument list, a.k.a. `"$@"`. 
If you are done with the argument list that you were invoked with (e.g.,
you’ve copied all the “positional parameters”  (arguments) into variables,
or otherwise processed them), you can use the arg list as an array:

```
if some_condition
then
    set -- -type f      # You could say `set -- "-type" "f"`, but it’s really unnecessary.
else
    set --
fi
if some_other_condition
then
    set -- "$@" -mtime +42
fi
# Similarly:    set -- "$@" -name "$fname"
find "$start_directory"  "$@"  other_find_args
```

The `"$@"` construct (which, historically, came first)
has the same semantics as `"${name[@]}"` —
it expands each argument (i.e., each element of the argument list)
to a separate word, as if you had typed `"$1" "$2" "$3" …`.

Excerpting from [the POSIX Shell Command Language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html),
under [2.5.2 Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02),

> **`@`**
>
>   Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one,
>   initially producing one field for each positional parameter that is set. 
>   …, the initial fields shall be retained as separate fields, …. 
>   If there are no positional parameters,
>   the expansion of
>   **`@`**
>   shall generate zero fields,
>   even when
>   **`@`**
>   is within double-quotes; …

The full text is somewhat cryptic;
the key point is that it specifies
that `"$@"` shall generate zero fields
when there are no positional parameters. 
Historical note: when `"$@"` was first introduced
in the Bourne shell (predecessor to bash) in 1979,
it had a bug that `"$@"` was replaced by a single empty string
when there were no positional parameters;
see [What does `${1+"$@"}` mean in a shell script,
and how does it differ from `"$@"`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68484/80216), 
[The Traditional Bourne Shell Family](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/index.html), 
[What does `${1+"$@"}` mean ...and where is it necessary?](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/bourne_args), 
and [`"$@"` versus `${1+"$@"}`](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/sh_dollar_at).

---

Arrays help with the first situation, too:

```
if some_condition
then
    ignorecase=(-i)     # You could say `ignorecase=("-i")`, but it’s really unnecessary.
else
    ignorecase=()       # Do not use any quotes on this command!
fi
grep  "${ignorecase[@]}"  other_grep_args
```

## ____________________

### P.S. (csh)

This should go without saying, but, for the benefit of folks who’re new here:
csh, tcsh, etc., are not Bourne/POSIX shells. 
They’re a whole different family. 
A horse of a different color. 
A whole other ball game. 
A different breed of cat. 
Birds of another feather. 
And, most particularly, a different can of worms.

Some of what’s been said on this page applies to csh;
such as: it’s a good idea to quote all your variables
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
But, in csh, every variable is an array —
it just so happens that almost every variable
is an array of only one element, and acts pretty similar
to an ordinary shell variable in Bourne/POSIX shells. 
And the syntax is awfully different (and I do mean ***awfully***). 
So we won't say anything more about csh-family shells here.

Comment: Note that in `csh`, you'd rather use `$var:q` than `"$var"` as the latter doesn't work for variables that contain newline characters (or if you want to quote the elements of the array individually, rather than join them with spaces into a single argument).

Comment: In bash, `bitrate="--bitrate 320"` works with `${bitrate:+$bitrate}`, and `bitrate=--bitrate 128` won't work `${bitrate:+"$bitrate"}` because it breaks the command. Is is safe to use `${variable:+$variable}` with no `"`?

Comment: @Freedo: I find your comment unclear.  I’m especially unclear what you want to know that I haven’t already said.  See the second “But what if” heading — “But what if I have a variable that I want/need to be split into words?”  That’s your situation, and you should be following the advice there.  But if you can’t (e.g., because you’re using a shell other than bash, ksh, zsh or yash, and you’re using `$@` for something else), or you simply refuse to use an array for other reasons, I refer you to “As discussed in the other answer”.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Your suggestion (using `${variable:+$variable}` with no `"`) will fail if IFS contains `-`, `0`, `2`, `3`, `a`, `b`, `e`, `i`, `r` or `t`.

Comment: Well my variable has both a,e,b,i 2 and 3 characters and still works fine with `${bitrate:+$bitrate}`

Comment: You seem not to be understanding what I’m saying.  Yes, ***of course*** your `bitrate` variable contains `a`, `e`, `b`, `i`, `2` and `3` — I listed all the characters that are in your variable.  The issue is whether the ***`IFS`*** variable contains them. Please read all the answers to the question.

Comment: What is IFS? I see a lot of talk about it, but nobody says what it is. without context is hard to someone that doesn't know what it is to understand

Comment: See [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784/80216), [What is the 'IFS'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16192/80216), [Understanding the default value of IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120575/80216), [Setting IFS for a single statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92187/80216) and [Split string using IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397205/80216).  Also related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216)   (And did you read all the answers to *this* question?)

Comment: Related: [Transform an array into arguments of a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29509/80216).

Comment: `criteria="-type f"` This would only work if I am the only one who can control the script.  What if I want to get the params from the user: `echo "Any additional parameters for the command?"; read criteria`. (Say user enters `type -f`) Now `type -f` is a joint string.  If I quote in a command `find "$criteria"`, it'll never work.

Comment: @TheMaster: It seems like you understand me perfectly and not at all, at the same time.  And what do *you* mean by ‘‘if I am the only one who can control the script.’’?  (1) Everybody knows that, if you let [Boris Badenov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Badenov) edit your code, [it’s not your code anymore](https://web.archive.org/web/20220819191352/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc722487(v=technet.10)).  If you accept input from an untrustworthy user and use it directly in commands, it’s not your computer anymore.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) I never said «`find "$criteria"`»; I said «`find $criteria`» ***(without quotes)*** — and then I proceeded to present a better way, ***with** quotes,* using an array. … … … … … … … The whole point of my answer was *to **debunk*** common “reasons” (excuses) for not using quotes.  If you didn’t grasp that point, I have to wonder what you *did* understand. … … … … … … … … P.S.  Do you believe that “joint string” is a standard term? I’m not familiar with it.

Comment: The bitrate case has a relatively simple (and portable) solution: rather than `bitrate='--bitrate 19200'` then use unquoted `$bitrate`, you can write `bitrate=19200` and then to use it, write `${bitrate:+ --bitrate "$bitrate" }` (harmless extra spaces inserted for clarity)

Answer (score 11):

I was skeptical of Stéphane’s answer, however it is possible to abuse `$#`:

```scala
$ set `seq 101`

$ IFS=0

$ printf '%s\n' $#
1
1

$ printf '%s\n' "$#"
101
```

or $?:

```
$ IFS=0

$ awk 'BEGIN {exit 101}'

$ status=$?

$ printf '%s\n' $status
1
1

$ printf '%s\n' "$status"
101
```

These are contrived examples, but the potential does exist.

Answer (score -6):

I defy the notion that I'm morally corrupt or technically incompetent if I don't quote my every variable in my every script, whether my own or in answers on SO.

The popular answer could be boiled down to one line at the end:

> *please avoid writing security sensitive code in shells*

The post presumes an attacker.  I suggest that 99% of shell scripts face no attack whatever, nor ever will.  They exist in `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME` for the users' convenience.  They control some kind of initialization which *by definition* is not subject to arbitrary input.

Your `~/.profile` does not face an attacker. Your 30-line awk script to parse a log file or prepare a database load probably doesn't, either.  Generalized advice to everywhere-and-always write shell scripts as though they faced an attack makes the vast majority of them more complex than they need be, and only encourages the notion that they can be made secure.

Does your script face an attacker?  OK, so take care, and maybe consider if running a shell script with root privileges is a good idea in that case.

**Edit**

The always-quote advice asserts quoting shell variables always prevents errors.  That is not the case.  To *blindly* prevent splitting and expansion when the input should not contain whitespace or wildcards invites semantic errors.

```
name=$(ls foo*.cfg)
...
if [ ! -f $name ]
then 
    touch $name
fi
```

If `$name` unexpectedly contains more than one one filename, the code above breaks with *binary operator expected*.  If "correctly" written with magic error-prevention quotes, it silently and incorrectly succeeds, creating a new, bogus file.  Doubtless it will go awry later in some inscrutable way that will be much harder to debug.

By not quoting `$name`, the script makes an implicit assertion that the contents will contain one name without embedded whitespace. That's a useful assertion. It won't touch more than one name, and it won't create silly one.  It will stop if, as should be the case, it's running with `-e`.  Else at least it will produce a message to alert you to where things went off the rails.

Comment: Quoting expansions to disable word splitting is also a correctness issue in a lot of contexts, definitely the ones involving filenames, since those can contain whitespace and people usually assume `foo *.txt` works on `.txt` files, even if one of them is called "shell gotchas.txt` instead of `shell_gotchas.txt`. The stuff one runs as convenience scripts can also accidentally be subject to untrusted input, again in the form of filenames, if you happen to be on a multiuser system, or one where some software allows uploading arbitrarily-named files (that would count against said software, too)

Comment: I also don't think the question as posted above presumes an attacker as it specifically _asks_ what the vulnerability could be, and in what context. Yes, your `.profile` probably doesn't face an attacker, usually, and neither does the awk script to parse log files on a somewhat closed system (but awk isn't relevant for shell script bugs anyway). And yes, it would probably be a good idea to write world-facing stuff with something other than the shell, and there are contexts where it might be safe to skip quotes. But you have to know the problems first to know when there's _no_ problem.

Comment: (And based on a truckload of questions on the site, people in general _don't_ know, hence the ceaseless hammering of the subject.)

Comment: I agree *know the problem* is a good idea.  It's easy to contrive examples in which an unquoted variable raises a syntax error in the presence of unexpected whitespace, where quotes would "solve" the problem by converting the syntax error into a semantic one. Absolutely, if the input is uncontrolled, measures must be taken to control it.  I consider that a front-edge problem, not something pervasive throughout the system or germane to all shell scripts.

Comment: Anything like `somecmd $file` where `$file` is supposed to contain one filename will fail if the filename has a space in it. I don't think there's anything contrived there, but it's also not a syntax error, and quotes would actually fix it. (No need to quote the "solve" -- it's not an expansion.)

Comment: "If `$name` unexpectedly contains more than one one filename...", well, for one, you can't safely put more than one filename in a scalar variable. How would tell apart the two filenames `foo` and `bar` from one filename `foo bar`? Or change the space to a newline if you like. Instead of using `name=$(ls foo*.cfg)`, you should be using an array, like `names=(foo*.cfg)`. Yes, of course people who put newlines in filenames other than for testing should be shot, but I don't think you can magic away spaces in filenames.

Comment: Even if we accept the idea of using a space-separated list to represent multiple filenames, there's still an error in the script in that it should then be checking that there's only one element in that "list" before trying to use the "whole list" in a context that can usefully take just one name. Letting `[` barf isn't a very robust way of dealing with a situation that breaks the assumptions the script makes. What if the `else` branch did something with `$name`?

Comment: Note that the main context of the "just effin' quote" rule is POSIX sh and Bash and similar shells, not fish or zsh where just `$foo` can actually refer to an actual list, and produce distinct arguments just like that. The question here is tagged with [tag:bash] and some of the other answers already mention zsh and csh as different.

Comment: "It will stop if, as should be the case, it's running with -e." -- well except that it won't, since `[` there is running inside the condition part of an `if`, where a program failing is normal and not cause for an error exit. Try it: `bash -e -c 'name="foo bar"; if [ -f $name ]; then echo yes; fi; echo end.'`. That's [BashFAQ 105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), btw, and also mentioned in [some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312631/170373) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65532/170373) on the site.

Comment: YMMV, I guess.  I get the output I'm accustomed to: `bash: line 0: [: foo: binary operator expected`.  I'm surprised anything else could happen because `-f` takes one operand, and anything after it that's not a `;` or newline is a syntax error. Look, there are lots of ways to make mistakes.  I'm only saying that quoting variables isn't a failsafe, and sometimes conceals errors.  Using quotes in the hope they'll prevent errors without knowing the input is itself an error.  The only preventative is to *think*.

Comment: YMMV regarding what?

Comment: `bash -e -c 'name="foo bar"; if [ -f $name ]` results in an error message in GNU bash, version 3.2.57 on my Macintosh.  Oh, I see your point.  `-e` doesn't cause termination; the command still prints "`end`".

Comment: yes, exactly, it doesn't stop, so some latter part of the script could still do something surprising. And anyway, I didn't see you address the problem of filenames themselves containing spaces.

Comment: In my work, filenames don't have spaces.  Because they don't, I can use `-f $name` freely, knowing that if `$name` resolves to more than one string, I'll at least see an error message.  It's a waste of time to write fully generalized code; *yagni* says write what you need, and only that.  Leave what you don't need for later, which may be never.  That's my objection to pedantic *always quote* advice.

Comment: yes, well, that's a rather important assumption to state, now isn't it? Because you didn't mention that at all in your post, and it took a thread of about a dozen comments and one week of time before you did mention that. Yes, sure, saying "You don't need to quote expansions giving filenames if you know they don't have spaces" pretty much works (if you also assume they don't contain glob characters). Then again, when giving out advice to the general public, as SE pretty much does, it makes sense to be general. And in general, people have filenames that contain whitespace, and more.

Comment: (Then again, adding that assumption to the post here doesn't exactly make it sound nicer; it turns into "I reject the notion that I'm incompetent if I don't quote, since _I_ know _my_ files/values never have whitespace in them"... Well, I don't know if anything I said helps explain the downvotes this post has gathered, or if it's just more irksome pedanticism, but anyway.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137263/discussion-between-james-k-lowden-and-ilkkachu).

Comment: The most expensive data loss event I've ever been personally present for was caused by someone who "knew" that the filenames they were handling (with data used to support customer billing) could never have anything but hexadecimal characters. That was true until there was a buffer overflow in a C library used by a Python interpreter generating new data being fed into this system and a filename with a whitespace-surrounded `*` was introduced. That file ages out, the retention policy enforcement script goes to delete it, and deletes all the _newer_ files too.

Comment: Yes, that's a once-in-a-decade bug; but if you could avoid it by maintaining a habit of writing reflexively cautious code... I don't find it defensible not to.

Comment: It's like sex: nobody cares what you do with cooperating programs in the privacy of your own home. But what you do in front of a classroom is held to a different standard. Quite simply, do not post insecure answers to forums, because you don't know who will copy it, how well they will understand it, and what threat profile it will face in their environment. Most threats are indirect: security system A calls subsystem B, which calls library C, which invokes validation D, performed by buggy script E. Or even less direct.

Comment: _In my work, filenames don't have spaces. Because they don't, I can use -f $name freely, knowing that if $name resolves to more than one string, I'll at least see an error message._ <<< Uuh, sure. Until that filename looks like `hello -o -delete`